# Apache Tomcat 8.0 Start failier on Eclipse MARS - JAVA EE

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

Following Eclipse version I have installed and I have testing Spring Simple Application called "CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial". This is a maven project. It was successfully built and when going to start with Apache tomcat it's getting error as follow.

***Java Version***

- java -version
- java version "1.8.0_65"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

***Eclipse Version***

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
- Build id: 20150924-1200

  ```
  SEVERE: A child container failed during start
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      ... 6 more

  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
  SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      ... 7 more
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      ... 9 more
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      ... 11 more

  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
  INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
  INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
  INFO: Stopping service Catalina
  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
  Feb 09, 2016 11:46:19 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
  SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
  ```

  Manual start-up and shut-down working without error.

  ```
  [root@csc bin]# ./startup.sh 
  Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
  Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
  Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/temp
  Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
  Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/bootstrap.jar:
  /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
  Tomcat started.

  [root@csc bin]# ./shutdown.sh 
  Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
  Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
  Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/temp
  Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
  Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/bootstrap.jar:
  /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
  ```

[image: when running application error starting tomcat after automatically shutdown]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're *not* running your eclipse as root. However, your "manual start-up" code implies that your manual startup was executed as root. This typically leads to the situation that many work-, temp and other files are owned by root and not writeable for an unprivileged user.

The fix is to change ownership of the files, e.g. to the user that you're executing eclipse with - typically your own account. Now that the files already belong to root, you'll have to do this as root as well:

```
sudo chown --recursive yourusername /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
```

(substitute *yourusername*, of course)

*Never* run a webserver like tomcat as root - you *always* want it to run as an unprivileged user. Otherwise any security issue on tomcat might mean immediate root access for an attacker

Comment: I changed like above but I am still getting same see the warning as                                 following                                                                                               `Feb 09, 2016 4:14:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CrunchifySpringMVCTutorial' did not find a matching property.
Feb 09, 2016 4:14:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log`                                     @Olaf Kock

Comment: ...but it starts now? That would fix the issue above. And the warning is just that: A warning. You can easily run with it (for now) or configure the debugger with the source path manually. At least that's a problem unrelated to your question above.

Comment: After deploying the tomcat server going **shut-down automatically** with above errors

Comment: I don't understand. Please give specific steps: What are you doing, what's happening? Is tomcat shutting down automatically when you start it up? Do you mean the "above errors" as in your question or as in your comment to my answer (which would just be a warning, typically coming up during startup, not shutdown)

Comment: **01.)** I added a tomcat server and started working fine.  **02.)** Ran application with the tomcat and then server went down with above errors and warnings. **03.)** When I try to restart the tomcat server again getting same errors and warnings **04.)** After remove the application from it's back to normal and working fine.

Comment: Whatever your application does - seems like you should debug what's happening on deployment of your application. Doesn't look like it's being related to eclipse. You might want to run it in a debugger and halt on occurrences of LifecycleException - see if you can figure out the condition under which it's thrown. Funny that there's no underlying root cause - or did you shorten the log?